# How to transfer session after being redirected to other page

Tags: php, session

I am trying to display inputted fields on another page using sessions. I was able to display simple strings, but when I try and add data fields from my submitted form, it turns up blank. Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

On page success of submitting information:

```
$username = sanitize_text_field( $_POST['username'] );
$user_login_username = $wpdb->get_var("SELECT username FROM login_first WHERE username = '$username'");
echo "Welcome back . $user_login_username";
session_start();
$_SESION['username'] = $user_login_username;
//yes is value that displays content on next page
wp_redirect("https://mwcti.com/test-page/?success=yes");
```

Results after being taken to other page:

```
if("yes" == $_GET['success']) 
{
    session_start();
    echo $_SESSION['username'];
    session_destroy();
}
```

Comment: `$_SESSION` is misspelled in your first code sample—it's missing an `S`. If this is copied-and-pasted from your running WordPress instance, that could be the reason it's not working as expected.

Comment: Thank you! It works!